# Wait for child process with timeout. Need idiomatic solution

Tags: go

Problem: Start a child process using *exec.Command* or *exec.CommandContext*, then wait until either the child process finishes running or the timeout occurs, whichever happens first. After the waiting is done do an appropriate action depending on whether the child process run to conclusion or timeout occurred.

I came up with something like this:

```
cmd = ...
go func() {
    cmd.Wait()
    close(childIsDone)
}

select {
case <- childIsDone:
    // job is done
case <- time.After(...):    
    // timeout
}
```

Is there any better way to do it? It feels like I missed something or *exec* module is missing *WaitWithDelay* or similar method.

Important: we don't want the child process to terminate after a curtain duration. What we want, is to ask it at some point "Could you please finish up in 10" and then act depending on the outcome.

Comment: It's better to describe your question more clearly if you don't want to stop the command even the timeout occured.

Comment: I think your solution is the simplest way to do that, but the `cmd.Wait()` in the goroutine should be `cmd.Run()` or `cmd.CombinedOutput()`